# Update a whole COLUMN from the previous value and a math operation

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a COLUMN named `Col1` in a table.

I want to divide each value in the column `Col1`by `x` if the value is less than K and by `y` if the value is more than K. So I try to update a value by itself and a factor.

I tried something like that but it didn't work : 
`UPDATE table1 SET Col1 =  (SELECT Col1 FROM table1 AS) / IF(val < K, x, y));`

I hope you will get me.

Thanks for your help.

(I should be reading a Mysql tutorial, my apologies but I'm not used to handle Mysql and I make query one time a year...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 SET Col1 = IF(col1 < K, col1/x, col1/y);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to test it. But how do it know `col1` value ?

Comment: It loops over the table, row by row. And updates col1. If the (old) col1 is smaller than K, it sets col1/x, else it sets col1/y.